# nginx how to get the request client ipaddress

Tags: node.js, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have ngnix proxying to a nodejs server. I am trying to read the request client ip address/host name in my nodejs, but it's always

```
::ffff:127.0.0.1
```

But in my nginx access log, I can see the client ip address printed, not sure why my nodejs server can't get it.

```
x.x.x.x - - [24/Aug/2017:14:28:01 -0700] "GET ...."
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Add the following to your nginx configuration stanza that proxies to NodeJS:

`proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;`

Now you can read the header 'X-Real-IP' in NodeJS

Comment: I have already tried that, in my nodejs, it's undefined. I will update the question with my nginx.conf

Comment: I just found there was another ngnix proxying between, that fixed it

Comment: 'X-Real-IP' in lowercase `req.headers['x-real-ip']` shows the ip

Comment: Thanks, Akber. Anyway, for flask its flask.request.headers.get('X-Real-IP').

Answer (score 5):

Use `proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;` as setting in location block where you are proxying the request.

In the server use the attribute "HTTP_X_REAL_IP"

For Example in python: 
`request.environ.get('HTTP_X_REAL_IP')
(or)
request.environ.get('HTTP_X_REAL_IP',request.environ.get('REMOTE_ADDR'))`