# How to get the ip address of a request machine using python (On Sanic)

Tags: python, python-3.x, curl, sanic

I am trying to get the IP address of the requesting computer on my server. I can successfully get the IP-address from request header if the request came from a web browser. The code example below. However, I cannot fetch the client IP, if I send the request via curl/postman. I checked the nginx log, and I found there is a log of my public IP when I sent a curl request. How can I achieve this?

PS: I am using the Sanic Framework.

`client_ip = request.headers.get('x-real-ip')`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [nginx how to get the request client ipaddress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45871225/nginx-how-to-get-the-request-client-ipaddress)

Comment: No. I want to get it through python.

Answer (score 2):

In `sanic`'s [docs for Request Data](https://sanic.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sanic/request_data.html):

> *ip* (str) - IP address of the requester.

Therefore, just use

```
client_ip = request.ip
```

Comment: Could not find description by the link provided in the answer, here's the relevant one (in 2022 :)): https://sanic.readthedocs.io/en/stable/sanic/api/core.html#sanic.request.Request.ip